# Monitor working on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, display, display-settings, display-driver

I started using my old monitor recently using a VGA-HDMI adapter. It worked the first time on my laptop running Windows 10 without making any changes to settings. Then I tried it on my work laptop and the monitor kept saying, "Input not supported" (probably because that laptop has a higher resolution). So, I connected it back to my laptop and now it displays the same message.

However, this message is only displayed when running Windows 10. When I dual boot into Pop OS, the display works fine. I've fiddled with all Windows Display settings (tried various resolutions and refresh rates) and even tried reinstalling the drivers. Not sure how to fix this.

**Details about the hardware**

- Personal Laptop - Dell Inspiron 5559
- Work Laptop - HP ProBook 440 G8
- HDMI to VGA adapter is non-branded one but it is in working
  condition
- Monitor - [HCL HCMELWBT11](https://manualzz.com/doc/57508099/hcl-hcmelwbt11-service-manual)

Comment: Give us some information about your computer model, display adapter and monitor. Are you using the same cable on the laptop as from when the monitor worked correctly? Are both the home & work computers found at your house, or did you transport the monitor to work?

Comment: @harrymc Have added details about the hardware to the question. Yes, I am using the same cable. Yes, both the laptops are at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Input Not Supported" can have two causes:

- Bad physical connection with the monitor
  (less likely since Linux works)
- The computer’s resolution doesn’t match with the monitor.

The second case is more likely. The explanation might be that the
monitor changed its resolution when connected to the work computer,
and now cannot work with Windows on the laptop.
Linux probably adapts itself better to the situation.

I would suggest:

- If the monitor has a Settings button, check its resolution setting,
  or reset the monitor's settings (if possible)
- In Windows, change the resolution of this monitor to what it was
  before.
  Check other settings in *Settings > System > Display*, including
  those in "Advanced display settings".
- Boot Windows in Safe Mode, run MSConfig, Boot tab, enable
  "Base video" and reboot normally

If none of the above works for you, perhaps it is some hardware
incompatibility after all.
You would need to change adapter and cable and monitor,
which might perhaps help.

(Note: If you have changed any settings in the BIOS in order to run Linux,
undo them.)

Comment: Well, I don't know what setting affected this but now it is working on my personal laptop but not on the work laptop. The work laptop has higher resolution and I dialed it down, trying every resolution all the way to 800 x 600 but it is still not working. It worked once but as soon as I disconnected and reconnected the cable. it stopped working again.

Comment: You might try another good quality cable and/or adapter, in case this is caused by hardware.